# Error Creating Linked Account in Razorpay: 'Merchant is not a partner

Tags: node.js, payment-gateway, razorpay

I've reviewed the Razorpay documentation and I'm still encountering this issue. It seems to be related to the merchant not being recognized as a partner. Could someone provide insights on why this error occurs and how to properly create a sub-merchant account on Razorpay? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Code

```
const createAccount = async () => {
  const accountData = {
    email: 'test@gmail.com',
    phone: '9000090000',
    legal_business_name: 'Acme Corp',
    contact_name: 'Gaurav Kumar',
  };
  instance.accounts.create(accountData, (error, account) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log({ error });
    } else {
      console.log({ account });
    }
  });
};
```

Error

```
error: {
  statusCode: 400,
  error: {
    code: 'BAD_REQUEST_ERROR',
    description: 'Merchant is not a partner',
    source: 'NA',
    step: 'NA',
    reason: 'NA',
    metadata: {},
    field: 'partner type'
  }
}
```